# Array out of Bounds error when trying to add to array

Tags: java

I have broken down my code and reviewed it 1 by 1 to see this error and I am not sure of how to handle it, I'm trying to read multiple lines from file and store the data into Array. I'm able to store `details[0]` as Username but when I try adding `details[1]` and `details[2]` I get the error. Can someone help me please?

Data in the file:

```
test|9f86d081884c7d659a2feaa0c55ad015a3bf4f1b2b0b822cd15d6c15b0f00a08|500
testing|9f86d081884c7d659a2feaa0c55ad015a3bf4f1b2b0b822cd15d6c15b0f00a08|400
testtry|9f86d081884c7d659a2feaa0c55ad015a3bf4f1b2b0b822cd15d6c15b0f00a08|300
testnew|9f86d081884c7d659a2feaa0c55ad015a3bf4f1b2b0b822cd15d6c15b0f00a08|200
```

The code is below

```
    Scanner read = new Scanner(new File("players.dat"));
    String line;

    ArrayList<String> players = new ArrayList<String>();
    while (read.hasNextLine()){
        line = read.nextLine();
        String[] details = line.split("\\|");
        String UserN = details[0];
        String Password = details[1];
        String Chips = details[2];
```

Comment: Is there an empty file at the end?

Comment: i am not sure of what u mean by empty file at the end but... when i split details[0] becomes all the data leaving details[1] to be empty

Answer (score 6):

You're probably reading a blank line. Never split without checking after that that the item exists.

Try to print the line you're splitting to see why you're getting the error. Tip for life: Always use the debugger, it's there for you.

Note: It's good that you escaped the `|` character, as `split` takes a regex, and `|` regex means: "empty string, or.. an empty string".

Comment: ok i check by printing the line, it looks ok to me, i think when i add to array i might have encountered a new line which is blank

Comment: Debug your code, check the content of `line` on each iteration. I can't see any other reason why you're having this exception.. (Unless the exception is from a different array) Otherwise, that's a sad day for humanity, computers had conquered the world.

Comment: Hi, i think i know the error , when it read details[1], it becomes blank. it seems that details[0] becomes all the 3 split String

Answer (score 0):

(This is an extended comment - unfortunately, it is not possible to put readable code in an actual comment.)

The bug is somewhere other than the code and data in the question.

The following is a simple program that applies the given code to the given data. It does not reproduce the problem. I strongly support the recommendation for further debug, and also suggest trying to construct an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org).

```
import java.io.Reader;
import java.io.StringReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Test {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    String inputData = "test|9f86d081884c7d659a2feaa0c55ad015a3bf4f1b2b0b822cd15d6c15b0f00a08|500\n"
        + "testing|9f86d081884c7d659a2feaa0c55ad015a3bf4f1b2b0b822cd15d6c15b0f00a08|400\n"
        + "testtry|9f86d081884c7d659a2feaa0c55ad015a3bf4f1b2b0b822cd15d6c15b0f00a08|300\n"
        + "testnew|9f86d081884c7d659a2feaa0c55ad015a3bf4f1b2b0b822cd15d6c15b0f00a08|200\n";
    Reader inputReader = new StringReader(inputData);
    Scanner read = new Scanner(inputReader);
    String line;

    ArrayList<String> players = new ArrayList<String>();
    while (read.hasNextLine()) {
      line = read.nextLine();
      String[] details = line.split("\\|");
      String UserN = details[0];
      String Password = details[1];
      String Chips = details[2];
      System.out.printf("UserN=%s, Password=%s, Chips=%s%n", UserN, Password,
          Chips);
    }
    read.close();
  }
}
```

Output:

```
UserN=test, Password=9f86d081884c7d659a2feaa0c55ad015a3bf4f1b2b0b822cd15d6c15b0f00a08, Chips=500
UserN=testing, Password=9f86d081884c7d659a2feaa0c55ad015a3bf4f1b2b0b822cd15d6c15b0f00a08, Chips=400
UserN=testtry, Password=9f86d081884c7d659a2feaa0c55ad015a3bf4f1b2b0b822cd15d6c15b0f00a08, Chips=300
UserN=testnew, Password=9f86d081884c7d659a2feaa0c55ad015a3bf4f1b2b0b822cd15d6c15b0f00a08, Chips=200
```